# Android tradefed does not recognise device

Tags: android, cts

im building new device and have to provide CTS review results,

```
unfortunately upon running java -cp ddmlib-prebuilt.jar;tradefed-prebuilt.jar;hosttestlib.jar;cts-tradefed.jar -DCTS_ROOT=D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools\android-cts\tools\cts com.android.cts.tradefed.command.CtsConsole
```

and then running a list devices command, tradefed returns empty list.

Can anyone advice if there are any hard pre-requisites for execution of tradefed?

Or any other guess as to what exactly may be the problem?

ps. Running a tests leaves immediate empty reply without no error code.

ps2. target is 4.4.4 kitkat

Answer (score 0):

Resolution found, problem was in PATH incorrectly set in windows and in executing command (must lead to main directory of CTS not to tradefed directory)